# How to setup a Gerrit mirror in a remote location

Tags: git, replication, mirror, gerrit

We use git with Gerrit for code reviewing in Europe and it works fine ;) The problem is that we have colleagues in Asia with an internet connection that makes cloning, pushing and pulling take ages. Is there a way to setup a Gerrit mirror so that every commit has to be transfered between Europe and Asia only once? I know Gerrit supports replication but I'm not sure that's the answer since I'd like to be able to push and pull on both sides.

Comment: I met similar issue on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258874/how-should-the-other-remote-site-using-gerrit-server-based-on-a-mirror-repo  could anyone come to help?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't use gerrit, but here problem doesn't seem to be that complex. You just need to create a "local" repository. Now for example set up a post-receive-hook on both sides, that push to each other. Now every time someone pushs something to your australian repository, it gets pushed to your mirror and you and your developers can push and pull from this one (which will then pushed to australia again).

Comment: If I remember correctly Gerrit doesn't fire the post-receive-hook :/

Comment: Gerrit is just a frontend, but the git repository itself should fire it.